# Link for username in People and Groups leads to 404 error

Tags: central-administration, user

On any site in our on-prem installation (SP 2016), if I go into "People and Groups" and click on the link for any given user, I get dropped into a 404 error page.

The username URLs follow this pattern:

```
http://{sitename}/{subsite path}/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={some GUID}
```

I am one of the members of the Central Admin group and can make adjustments in CA. But, I don't want to just go clicking wildly. Any guidance on where username hyperlinks are supposed to go and how to repair broken links?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on the name should take you to that user's MySite page, or Delve if you have hybrid MySites configured.  I'd bet that you don't have either of these options configured.  If you go to a SharePoint site, not Central Admin, and click on a user's name like that, does it take you to the users MySite / Delve, or to the user information list info for that user?  If it takes you to the user information list info, then again this points to not having MySites or Hybrid MySites configured.

Comment: Clicking the link in the manner you describe takes me to a 404 error page. However, the address bar contents follow this pattern (which looks like a URL for MySite, maybe?...):

```
http://{site}/my/Person.aspx?accountname=i%3A0%23%2Ew%7C{domain}%5C{username}&Source=http%3A%2F%2F{site}%2F%5Flayouts%2Fuserdisp%2Easpx%3FForce%3D1%26ID%3D22%26
```

Comment: That appears to be a MySite URL, my best guess is that MySites are not configured for the farm.

Comment: Marking as answer, then. Though, it leaves me with more questions about how to run a Sharepoint installation without MySites (we don't need or want them). I'll post those in another thread.